# How do I send data which contains a double-quote using JSON?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I have a problem with JSON if our data has double quotes like this:  " 15" " (15 inch).

JSON is not parsing it.

My code looks like this:

```
    String strheader = convert.ToString(dt.table[0].rows[0]["Size"]);
    Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    Response.Write(strheader);
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 4):

You need to escape it.

```
 { book: "How to code C++ in 24 hour steps", author: "O\"Reilly" }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just escape the inner `"` by adding a `\` before it:

```
" 15\" "
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a Json library like [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) or [Simple Json](http://simplejson.codeplex.com/) for the task since them will escape your data automaticaly.

If it is just a simple task then just escape it manually like some have suggested

Answer (score 0):

Give a look at the class [DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb908432.aspx)